# Can't read updated variable

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, rotation

I need to stop/resume the rotation of a fan when a certain key is pressed, so I wrote this C# code:

```
public bool rotationFlag = false;

void Update()
{
   if(rotationFlag)
   {
      fan.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationAngle);
   }
}

public void commuteFan()
{
        rotationFlag = !rotationFlag;
}
```

`cummuteFan()` method is called when I press the button.

the variable starts on false and the fan correctly doesn't ratate, when I hit the button, the method is called, the variable values changes and the starts to rotate, but if I want to stop it, it doesn't work anymore. debug tells me that the value is correctly changed to false in `commuteFan()` but `update()` continues to read the old value (true) and the fan doesn't stop.

Comment: Are you tracing the value in `commute` and in `update`?

Comment: the rotate method rotate the object of the given angle every times it's called, so it doesn't start the rotation, it's called every frame as it's placed inside update().

what do you mean with tracing?

Comment: I checked [this video](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/translate-and-rotate) and edited my previous comment. But the video says that rotate should only be used in "kinematic" objects - I don't know what that means - but I understood that when using physics with an object you should avoit rotating the way you did (I don't know if that is your case).

Comment: ok, but I'm not using physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I don't know why, but I created a class with only the bool along with getter/setter methods in it and it works know

Answer (score 0):

So you had your variable as `public`, which means that any other part of the project could easily edit it. In your case you were changing it via the editor.

To avoid this kind of problems in the future try using protection.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isRotating = false;

    public void setIsRotating(bool status)
    {
        isRotating = status;
    }

    public bool getIsRotating()
    {
        return isRotating;
    }
}
```

Coding like this will save you a lot of headaches later on.

Comment: nope, I also tried to do something like this, but the problem was still there

Comment: That is almost impossible. Either way you should post how you fixed it and then accept your own answer.